# Don't want to use columns in the COUNT which are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have asked a question with the same query earlier but this time the question is different so I am posting another question. Below is the sql stored procedure query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PostedDate] Desc)AS RowNumber,[Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate], 
       ISNULL(AVG([Rating].[RatingValue]), 0) AverageRating, COUNT([Rating].[RatingValue]) RatingCount
       INTO #DealResults1
       FROM [Products]
       LEFT OUTER  JOIN [Rating] ON [Product].[Id] = [Rating].[ProductId]
       WHERE [City] = CASE WHEN @CityId IS NULL THEN [City] ELSE @CityId END 
       AND [Description] IS NOT NULL  
       Group by [Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate]
       ORDER BY [PostedDate] Desc
```

This is the query for 1 day. I have changed the table structure and now it is like this,

```
Id      Rating_Monday      Rating_Tuesday        Rating_Wednesday .......
 1            3.0                NULL                    NULL
 2            3.5                NULL                    NULL
 3            NULL               2.0                     NULL
 4            NULL               3.0                     NULL
 5            NULL               1.5                     NULL
 6            NULL               NULL                    1.0
 7            NULL               NULL                     2.5
 8            NULL               NULL                     4.5
```

On Monday, value for all other days will be Null. Now for Monday the rating selected is Rating_Monday. Everything works fine. In the above query there are two important parts which are,

```
ISNULL(AVG([Rating].[Rating_Monday]), 0) AverageRating
COUNT([Rating].[Rating_Monday]) RatingCount
```

Average is selected absolutely fine but RatingCount is wrong because it is selected according to row count and does not check for the Null value.

Comment: You know it's not necessary to put `[]'s` around every field right?

Comment: @C Sharper. Yes I know that I am just used to write like this mostly.

Comment: Why down voted? Strange.

Comment: You should get out of that habit, it makes the code harder/very annoying to read.

Comment: Ok I will get out of this habit. Beside it is easier for me to read and I don't like Alias. But everyone has their own preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a case can solve this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PostedDate] Desc)AS RowNumber,[Products].[Id], [Name],  [Description], [PostedDate], 
   ISNULL(AVG([Rating].[RatingValue]), 0) AverageRating, 
   SUM(case  when (Rating.RatingValue) is null then 0 else 1 END) RatingCount
   INTO #DealResults1
   FROM [Products]
   LEFT OUTER  JOIN [Rating] ON [Product].[Id] = [Rating].[ProductId]
   WHERE [City] = CASE WHEN @CityId IS NULL THEN [City] ELSE @CityId END 
   AND [Description] IS NOT NULL  
   Group by [Products].[Id], [Name], [Description], [PostedDate]
   ORDER BY [PostedDate] Desc
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am marking it as answer as this was the first answer.

Comment: In theory this answer should give exactly the same result as the query in the question.

Comment: @MartinBrown the problem is with the ISNULL it is bringing all the null columns into the result set, so all rows are being counted.

Comment: But the query given in the question does not have an ISNULL in the COUNT expression.

Answer (score 2):

COUNT(expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the **number of nonnull values**.

You may look into using the OVER clause : `COUNT(EmployeeID) OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentID) AS EmployeesPerDept`

See [COUNT (Transact SLQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the count:

```
sum(case when [Rating].[Rating_monday] is null then 0 else 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

To count use `condition aggragate` logic.

`Case statement` will convert your `NULL` values to `0` on that put a `SUM aggregate` which will help you to count the rows only those are `NOT NULL`

```
SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY [PostedDate] DESC)        AS RowNumber,
       [Products].[Id],
       [Name],
       [Description],
       [PostedDate],
       Isnull(Avg([Rating].[RatingValue]), 0) AverageRating,
       Sum(CASE WHEN [Rating].[Rating_monday] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) RatingCount
INTO   #DealResults1
FROM   [Products]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rating]
                    ON [Product].[Id] = [Rating].[ProductId]
WHERE  [City] = CASE WHEN @CityId IS NULL THEN [City] ELSE @CityId END
       AND [Description] IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY [Products].[Id],
          [Name],
          [Description],
          [PostedDate]
ORDER  BY [PostedDate] DESC
```

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that would return the same result as the query in the question seeing that COUNT() does not normally count null values. Any idea why it does here? I would have thought that using COUNT(*) would have the same effect as this.

Comment: @MartinBrown The trick was to insert a `CASE … END` statement inside the `SUM`. The case will return a 1 when the `[Rating].[Rating_monday]` is `NOT  NULL` we are looking for, and a 0 otherwise. The sum will then execute to add up all of those 0s and 1s. A 0 will not add anything, so we will effectively end up counting the values which are `NOT NULL`

Comment: However according to the Microsoft documentation and my tests with SQL Server 2008 R2. COUNT([Rating].[Rating_monday]) does not count nulls anyway.

Comment: If you had written the opposite Sum(CASE WHEN [Rating].[Rating_monday] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) I can see how that would be different to COUNT([Rating].[Rating_monday]) but you haven't you have added up the number of rows that are not null which is exactly what COUNT([Rating].[Rating_monday]) is supposed to do.

Comment: @MartinBrown - Yes i see that you are right both my query and question is doing the same thing. i didn't know about the `COUNT([Rating].[Rating_monday])` and `count(*)` difference.

Comment: Interestingly though, the accepted answer proposes the same solution as this one. Which leads me to believe that the query was actually giving the OP the correct answer all along.

Comment: @MartinBrown - Yes even am wondering how it is making a difference to OP